# TYPO3 FAL Label for Edit Form

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, fal

[image]

I wrote an extension for a slider. It all works well. My last problem is this: If I add an image in the list view, then the label appears with the HTML tags above. How can I customize the label or remove the tags?

```
'image' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:abc_slider/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_abcslider_domain_model_slider.image',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'image',
            [
                'appearance' => [
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                ],
                'foreign_types' => [
                    '0' => [
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                        'showitem' => '
                        --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                        --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ]
                ],
                'maxitems' => 1
            ],
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
        ),
    ],
```

Do i need something like this? `foreign_match_fields`